# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'b'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, indirection

I have the following code:

```
N1 = int(input())
a = set(list(map(int, input().split())))
N2 = int(input())
for i in range(N2):
    b = input().split()
    c = set(list(map(int, input().split())))
    a.b[0](c)
print(sum(a))
```

With typical input, the list `b` looks like this:

```
b = ['intersection_update', '10']
```

What is the issue with `a.b[0](c)`? Apparently I am not evaluating it correctly.

The concept seems fine, but it seems like set `a` is not able to take an attribute which is actually an element of a list.

what I want to evaluate is:

```
a.intersection_update(c)
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 7, in 
    a.b[0](c)
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that kind of indirect attribute access using the dot operator in Python. Use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) instead:

```
>>> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> c = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
>>> b = ['intersection_update', '10']
>>> getattr(a, b[0])(c)
>>> a
{3, 4, 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `getattr`, to get an attribute who's name stored as a string in another variable:

```
getattr(a, b[0])(c)
```

Your current code is looking for an attribute named `b` on the `a` set.